# Handle fail over in High avalibity?

Tags: java, tomcat, load-balancing, high-availability

Please consider below scenario.

I have implemented apache load balancer using mod jk. There are three tomcat behind apache load balancer. They all are in diffrerent machines. Let's say tomcat-1 is serving a request & before completing a request it goes down due to some issue.As Tomcat clustering has been configured, other two tomcat will handle further request. But how to handle that failed request which has already been accepted by tomcat-1. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have your proxy retry your request on another node after a failure, mod jk would need to know that a request was idemopotent.

I do see that adding this knowledge of idemoptency was discussed a long time ago.  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39692

I doubt that they implemented this functionality.

I have seen other reverse proxy solutions implement an idempotency identifier.  I seem to remember Weblogic having this ability.  I have also seen it with certain hardware proxies.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.